# Doxygen custom CSS for private, protected and public items

Tags: c++, css, doxygen

**BACKGROUND**
I'm using Doxygen v1.8.14 to document some embedded C++ projects for the developers. Documented class member functions' access modifiers are marked private, protected or public with a small label far to the right in the item's headline. When browsing the documentation, one has to look for this label far off from where the function name is located.

[image]

**INTENDED RESULT**
I would like to change the item's header background to blue (private), yellow (protected) and green (public) to easier identify them.

[image]

**PROBLEM**
I have browsed through the customdoxygen.css file but can't find any tags related to the C++ *access modifiers* (private, protected and public). I also inspected the HTML and CSS in Firefox but it seems like Doxygen don't distinguish the access modifiers (they are all the same CSS class). The access modifier are plain text in a  tag (except public that doesn't have the  tag).

```
<span class="mlabel">private</span>
```

In an earlier project I used ALIAS to redefine how code examples are shown, but that required a new Doxygen markup command to be used (the alias).

Any ideas of how to do this or if it's even possible?

Comment: Hi @MaxKielland, as it was too difficult to describe my suggestion in a comment, I posted an answer. Now, even that I am confident with the approach I have not validated the pseud-code (hope I this is not evil). So if my suggestion make sense please keep me posted and we can edit so it really works for future readers :)

Comment: At the moment this is, to the best of my knowledge, not possible, also not in the current doxygen 1.8.17 version. Question is of course as well what to do with multiple labels like you already gave "inline' + "protected".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite trivial and I had done something similar in the past (that I had forgot all about). @albert and @diogoslima reminded me of the HTML_HEADER config setting and then I remembered my old project. I had a look at it and then it was easy.

They key here is to not touch any original files, or at least as little as possible.
First of all you need to generate the template files for customization.

```
doxygen -w html header.html footer.html memberaccess.css
```

For this purpose you can delete the `footer.html`, it won't be used here.
Open the `header.html` and add the following line in the `<head>` section (just before `$treeview` is a nice spot):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="$relpath^memberaccess.js"></script>
```

...then add the `onload` event to the `<body>` tag.

```
<body onload="DoAccessModifiers()">
```

That's it, save the `header.html` file.

Open the `memberaccess.css` file and replace all its content with this:

```
/* fix empty documents */
.empty {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}

/* default access colors */
.memtitle {
    padding: 8px;
    border-color: #a8b8d9
    border-top: 1px solid;
    border-left: 1px solid;
    border-right: 1px solid;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    background-image: none;
    background-color: #e2e8f2;
    color: #253555;
    line-height: 1.25;
    font-weight: 300;
    float:left;
}

/* private access colors */
.private {
      border-top: 1px solid;
      border-left: 1px solid;
      border-right: 1px solid;
      border-color: #7e96c7;
      /*color: #253555;*/
      background-color: #dfe5f1;
}

/* protected access colors */
.protected {
      border-top: 1px solid;
      border-left: 1px solid;
      border-right: 1px solid;
      border-color: #ffba3b;
      /*color: #253555;*/
      background-color: #ffe9c0;
}

/* public access colors */
.public {
      border-top: 1px solid;
      border-left: 1px solid;
      border-right: 1px solid;
      border-color: #93c77e;
      /*color: #253555;*/
      background-color: #e4f1df;
}

/* default label colors */
span.mlabel {
      background-color: #728dc1;
      border-top:1px solid #5373b4;
      border-left:1px solid #5373b4;
      border-right:1px solid #c4cfe5;
      border-bottom:1px solid #c4cfe5;
      text-shadow: none;
      color: white;
      margin-right: 4px;
      padding: 2px 3px;
      border-radius: 3px;
      font-size: 7pt;
      white-space: nowrap;
      vertical-align: middle;
}

/* private label colors */
span.private {
      background-color: #728dc1;
      border-top:1px solid #5373b4;
      border-left:1px solid #5373b4;
      border-right:1px solid #c4cfe5;
      border-bottom:1px solid #c4cfe5;
      /*color: white;*/
}

/* ptotected label colors */
span.protected {
      background-color: #728dc1;
      border-top:1px solid #5373b4;
      border-left:1px solid #5373b4;
      border-right:1px solid #c4cfe5;
      border-bottom:1px solid #c4cfe5;
      /*color: white;*/
}

/* inherited label colors */
span.inherited {
      background-color: #728dc1;
      border-top:1px solid #5373b4;
      border-left:1px solid #5373b4;
      border-right:1px solid #c4cfe5;
      border-bottom:1px solid #c4cfe5;
      /*color: white;*/
}

/* strong label colors */
span.strong {
      background-color: #728dc1;
      border-top:1px solid #5373b4;
      border-left:1px solid #5373b4;
      border-right:1px solid #c4cfe5;
      border-bottom:1px solid #c4cfe5;
      /*color: white;*/
}

/* static label colors */
span.static {
      background-color: #728dc1;
      border-top:1px solid #5373b4;
      border-left:1px solid #5373b4;
      border-right:1px solid #c4cfe5;
      border-bottom:1px solid #c4cfe5;
      /*color: white;*/
}

/* inline label colors */
span.inline {
      background-color: #728dc1;
      border-top:1px solid #5373b4;
      border-left:1px solid #5373b4;
      border-right:1px solid #c4cfe5;
      border-bottom:1px solid #c4cfe5;
      /*color: white;*/
}

/* virtual label colors */
span.virtual {
      background-color: #bbbbbb;
      border-top:1px solid #606060;
      border-left:1px solid #505050;
      border-right:1px solid #c0c0c0;
      border-bottom:1px solid #c0c0c0;
      color: #404040;
}

/* pure virtual label colors */
span.purevirtual {
      background-color: #ffffff;
      border-top:1px solid #606060;
      border-left:1px solid #505050;
      border-right:1px solid #c0c0c0;
      border-bottom:1px solid #c0c0c0;
      color: #000000;
}

/* delete label colors */
span.delete {
      background-color: #ca3939;
      border-top:1px solid #902626;
      border-left:1px solid #902626;
      border-right:1px solid #eab0b0;
      border-bottom:1px solid #eab0b0;
      /*color: white;*/
}
```

Then create the `memberaccess.js` file:

```
function GetAccessModifier(item) {
  access = 'public';
  Array.prototype.slice.call(item.getElementsByClassName('mlabel')).forEach(function(label) {
    if (label.innerText == 'private' || label.innerText == 'protected') { access = label.innerText; }
    label.className += ' '+label.innerText.replace(/ /g, '');
  });
  return access;
}

function DoAccessModifiers() {
  Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('memitem')).forEach(function(item) {
    var title = item.previousElementSibling;
    doc = item.getElementsByClassName('memdoc')[0];
    item = item.getElementsByClassName('memproto')[0];
    modifier = " "+GetAccessModifier(item);
    title.className += modifier;
    item.className += modifier;
    if(doc.childElementCount == 0) { item.className += ' empty'; doc.parentNode.removeChild(doc); }
  });
}
```

Now when all files has been prepared we only need to tell the doxygen configuration to use them. I'm lazy and prefer the `DoxyWizard` to create configurations, but you can hack into your favorite configuration file with a text editor if you like.

```
HTML_HEADER           = header.html
HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET = memberaccess.css
HTML_EXTRA_FILES      = memberaccess.js
```

DONE!

To change colors, edit the `memberaccess.css` file:

```
.private
.protected
.public
```

These classes defines the title and item background and borders.

```
span.xxxx
```

These classes controls the small labels to the right in each item. The `xxxx` is the same as the label's text (whitespaces removed).

I hope this is of use for anyone landing here.

Answer (score 1):

Bad news – I don’t believe Doxygen has a specific command/config to support this level of customization over the generated HTML output.

**Good news** – You can get really creative with the existing support to inject custom HTML, such as the [HTML_HEADER tag](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_html_header). For example, you could include a JavaScript to check the label and update the background color *onload()*.
Here is a pseudo-code (alert - I have not tested it) showing the suggested approach:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Go over all labels in the file 
var labels = document.getElementsByClassName("mlabel");
for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
   // Set all private labels to red
   if(labels.item(i).textContent == “private”) {
       labels.item(i).style.backgroundColor = "red";
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I would not do this with a `\htmlinclude` as you have to insert this everywhere (very error prone as it is easy to forget), I would add it to the `HTML_HEADER`

Comment: Problem will also be that it is not only the "mlabel" / "mlabels" but also some of the surrounding tags and other tags.

Comment: Makes sense @albert, thanks for the comments! I will update the answer to suggest HTML_HEADER. As for the exact generated HTML, maybe OP could update the question with a few of the elements around the span?

Comment: @albert and diogoslima, thank you for the tip. I will see what JavaScript libraries are in the standard html generation. I don't want to be pending on external content. If JQuery is included it would be quite "easy" to do the OnLoad() suggestion. I will get back and update when I have done some testing.

Comment: Sure @MaxKielland, good luck and keep us posted plz! Ohh, and please notice the pseudo-code shared is not using JQuery, just the core functionally supported by the browser with the Browser Application Programming Interfaces... so no need to add libraries.

Comment: I have done something similar when I added a tabbed example code window with one tab for each programming language. You are right, I did that one without JQuery so I think I will manage with the standard DOM.

Comment: I made a "system" for easy reconfiguration of colors on access modiffiers and the small labels at the right. They can now all be changed individually without editing any original files. I posted my own answer, it's to much to explain here in the comment section.

Comment: Great, I am happy you achieved your goal @MaxKielland :)